# can not edit a value of a binary row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

hi i forget admin password but i can connect to sql
i try to replace another user password to recover
but got this error:

[image: edit sql row]

the pass field is like this :

[image: pass]

Comment: Editting user name and password directly shouldn't be possible with a good security model. Use the application's password recovery process; whatever that is.

Comment: Trying to hack your way through security is not a viable path. So your question becomes "how do i regain adminstrative access to an server instance".

Comment: @SMor that isn't SQL Server's `LOGIN`/`USER` information; `sys.principles` and `sys.users` don't have any of those columns. This is clearly an application's user credential information, so only the those who know the application will know how the password recovery process works.

Comment: @SMor i have the sql sa that can access to that table so it not a hack a sql server

Comment: @Larnu there is no recovery app the program is not available

Comment: Then speak to the application vendor for support, @Vahid . Then learn your lesson, and purchase a password management application.

Comment: "replace a password" is hacking

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is asking how to get around password authentication for an application. Without context, this could easily be interpreted as the user trying to gain administrative privileges to an environment that they should not. Such questions should not be endorsed on the network, as that would result in the users here being implicitly involved in a security/data breach. If the OP truly has lost access they should contact the software vendor for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
UPDATE [my_users_table]
SET [pas] = CAST('newpass' AS VARBINARY(MAX))
WHERE [nam] = 'admin'
```

Open new window and try to set the password like this. Anyway, if the data is encrypted and then stored as binary, you will first need to get a valid encrypted binary before setting the new password.

```
UPDATE [my_users_table]
SET [pas] = 0x0DE3446D8F782E9B
WHERE [nam] = 'admin'
```

Comment: I really hope that this doesn't work; it means that the OP is storing (as good as) plain text passwords, which is a ***HUGE*** security flaw. Someone should not be able to view every single user's password with `SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(100),pas) FROM SomeTable;`